Black faces in rendering due to double thickness mesh
You can see in my video clip below my issue is that my mesh has double-thickness faces on some portions of the mesh. What is the easiest way to either clean this up without having to recreate it all or even make the rendering flatten the mesh so it doesnt render as black? This mesh was imported from SW and not created in blender.
Link to the video of my issue
File Location
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/bptd28djviwdpizr9sasf/Panel_Issue.blend?rlkey=cf5fuezgmkt27e0u4nazbsp68&st=dtcwfd54&dl=0



If you mean that the faces are overlapping, maybe try a M > Merge by Distance in Edit mode? If it doesn't i guess you have no other solution but to remove the faces "manually"?

I havent had any luck with using the merge by distance because the overlapping faces are not lined up. I have attached the file if anyone would like to take a look at a quick fix. I don't really know of an efficient fix to select all the faces manually because it gets tricky trying to select just one layer of the overlap...

maybe there's an easy way to do it that i don't know, but anyway you could easily redo it from scratch

Agreed on this case I just recreated the simple mesh from scratch. This occasionally happens on larger complex meshes that would require hours of rebuilding so I figured I would reach out for a solution on something simple for easy explanation of the issue.
Is there a way to make overlapping meshes appear flattened in renders and not have the "black artifacts" in the renderings?

If the faces are overlapping they will appear black in Cycles renders, there's now way to avoid that, except correct the topology, as for mesh appearing flat, I'm not sure what you mean
